# How to iterate through a list with aiohttp?

Tags: python, aiohttp

This is my first time trying out `aiohttp`. I'm struggling with the following script. I don't know how to iterate through a list in this example. It only prints one item from the list, and the loop ends. Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

```
import aiohttp, asyncio requests, re
from requests import Session
session = Session()

link = f"https://pastebin.com/raw/MW2KJNc3"
orange = []
h = session.get(link).text
urls = re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', h)

for url in urls:
    orange.append(f"{url}")

pear = list(dict.fromkeys(orange))

bottle = []

async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:

            bottle.append((url, response.status))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

print(bottle)
```

Comment: You must again iterate through "urls" or "orange" in the "main" routine to append for each entry in "urls" an entry in "bottle".

Comment: Isn’t that’s what’s happening above? I have the `append()` function, I put `url` inside it, there is `loop.run_until_complete(main())` so iteration should happen. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "run_until_complete" means to run until the routine "main" completely ran. As "main" doesn't contain a loop it only appends one item to "bottle" and ends.